# Calculate directional derivative at $(0, 0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, piecewise-continuity

I need to calculate the partial derivative for the function $f$, that is $f(x, y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ when $(x, y) \neq (0,0)$ and $0$ when $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

I can calculate the partial derivative for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$. However, how do I calculate the partial derivative at $(0, 0)$ in the direction of the vector $v = <1, 1>$?

Comment: Have you try to use the very definition using limits?

Comment: I did, but it asks me according to the vector $(1, 1)$, and that's why I got stuck. Forgot to mention. I will edit the question.

Comment: Then you have to calculate $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} (f(h,h)-f(0,0))/h$. And by the way, you should change the title after your update as you're no more computing a partial derivative but a directional derivative.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$ \frac{f(t,t)-f(0,0)}{t}=1$$

for all $t \ne 0.$ Hence

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (0,0)=1.$$